# How to change text font style in a Word 2013 Add-In

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am developing an add-in for Word 2013 that includes a ribbon. I want to know how can I change text font name and style from the ribbon (i.e. when clicking on a button)

I have this code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range sel =  Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
sel.Font.Bold = 1;
sel.Font.Name = "Segoe UI";
```

but it is not effecting the text selected.

Comment: Check [How to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b7k14a4.aspx) at  microsoft site.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting a paragraph within the document for the range not the application. 
Something like this.

```
 // Set the Range to the first paragraph.   
Word.Document document = this.Application.ActiveDocument;  
Word.Range rng = document.Paragraphs[1].Range;
```